# Insert ignore multiple array?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How to execure query like this in laravel with DB::Table or something like ??

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO 'banban' ('column') values('value1', 'value2')

DB::table('table')->insertIgnore( array(
   array('column'=>'value1',),
   array('column'=>'value2')
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how to do this with Fluent besides using `DB::raw()`, but Eloquent has a `firstOrNew()`

```
// Gets a user with fname of 'john' and lname of 'smith' or creates a new model and sets these properties.
$user = User::firstOrNew(['fname' => 'john', 'lname' => 'smith']);

// Lets say you want to activate john smith
$user->activated = true;

// Saves the new model or existing model (whatever it was)
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I am using in a static functon of my \App\Model to add multiple values with insert ignore. This code is a compilation of different answers I came across on StackOverflow.

Tested and working on Laravel 5.6 with PHP 7.1.3

```
$keys = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3'];

foreach ($whatever as $result) {
    $banban = [];
    $banban[] = $result->value1;
    $banban[] = $result->value2;
    $banban[] = $result->value3;

    $values[] = $banban;
}

return DB::insert(
    'INSERT IGNORE INTO ' . with(new self)->getTable() .
    '(' . implode(',', $keys) . ') values ' .
    substr(str_repeat('(?' . str_repeat(',?', count($keys) - 1) . '),', count($values)), 0, -1),
    array_merge(...$values)
);
```

Some explanations:

`with(new self)` returns a new instance of your model. It's an easy way to get the Model table name in a static function.

`substr(...,0,-1)` is used to remove the latest comma of the "values"

`str_repeat` is used twice to create the "(?,?,?)" placeholders and the "?" inside.

`array_merge(...$values)` flatters the array of values. This is also why `$values` can't have custom keys.

Hope this helps.